# How to Find Rhyming Notes in Bansuri

Tags: bansuri, interpretation, saptak

Please note, I am NOT asking for notes interpretation, I am simply asking how to determine rhyming notes for Bansuri.

For several months I was following this Tum Hi Ho tutorial (and I am 95% done, so I don't want to quit now) ,

Towards the end, the notes Harsh Dave is playing doesn't sound same when I play. Maybe because I have A-Scale Bansuri, or maybe because I am beginner.

For instance, in 7:06 he sings

```
da da pa da da
da ni ni.. pa da
```

However when I played it, it didn't sound right. Finally, I figured I should change the last `da` to `ga`. Now I play the following and it sounds like he sings and plays on Bansuri

```
da da pa da da
da ni ni.. pa ga
```

I need to know how to make certain notes rhyme.

I have been struggling for past month with following on 7:36

```
ma ma ga ma ga ma ma ga re
ma ma ga ma ga ma ga sa re
```

When I play last three notes `ga sa re` it doesn't sound right.

I listened to video over and over to make sure I heard Harsh Dave correct.

Question, how do I find rhyme for `ma ga re` in first line, so that it replaces `ga sa re` in second line, i.e.

```
ma ma ga ma ga ma ma ga re
ma ma ga ma ga ma ? ? ?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One reason for your struggle is that Dave Harsh is singing the swaras *incorrectly* at many points.

You are correct that at 7:06 the last *dha* should be a *ga* (however I do hear Dave say *ga* and not *dha*).

You are also correct that at 7:36 *ga sa re* is incorrect. Dave is not notating the music accurately here, causing your confusion. Even based on a cursory listen through, I can tell that there are a few other points where Dave is inaccurate or unclear in notating the song.

The way out is, as you might have guessed, to trust your ear rather than the given notation. It is good that you are able to sense with your ear that some notes are not sounding quite right. With continued practice, you will not only be able to accurately point out when notes are sung wrong, but also notate songs confidently by yourself.

All the best.